to determine the appropriate threshold of the z-score for the non-normally distributed data
I am interested in CPI. And I need to identify outliers in the series. For that, my instructor mentioned about  the number of standard deviations from the mean that a data point is. This is Z-score.
I read the following information on Z-score:" if you are looking at data that is normally distributed, then a Z-score of 3 is a good threshold. However, if you are looking at data that is not normally distributed, then you may want to use a different threshold."
My data is not normally distributed. The descriptive statistics of the data is as follows:



How can I determine the appropriate threshold for the z-score?
I also calculated z-scores for all observations in the data as follows:

The Graph in the case that the threshold is 2

The Graph in the case that the threshold is 2.5

The Graph in the case that the threshold is 3

Or, there might be different threshold from these I posted.
Please share your ideas about how to determine the suitable threshold to detect correct outliers?
Editted:
Firstly, fit a loess curve as follows:

Secondly fit a smooth spline curve as follows:


If your distribution is normally distributed with known mean and standard deviation, then about $0.27%$ of the distribution will be $3$ or more standard deviations from the mean; with $256$ observations, you might expect $0.69$ of them to be $3$ or more standard deviations from the mean.  But in the worst case with a non-normal distribution, the one-sided Chebyshev inequality suggests  up to $10%$ of the distribution can be $3$ or more standard deviations from the mean.  This is not helpful in your example.

Thank you! Well, how can I determine outliers in my example? @Henry

This needs a cross-reference to your other recent thread. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/649330/methods-for-detecting-outliers-in-a-time-series

TL:DR  I'm not sure this is needed, but, if it is, there will not be a simple method of doing it.
Longer answer:
First, your data look pretty darn normal. Formal tests of normality are lousy. The best way to look at it is a quantile normal plot. But your skewness aren't that odd and your mean is quite close to your median. The kurtosis is a bit high.
Second, if you do decide your data is not normal, and you decide that the reason is skewness, then you might not want to use mean and SD. For skewed distributions, the mean is usually regarded as a poor measure of central tendency, and the SD formula contains the mean, so it shouldn't be used either. Outliers can also throw off the mean and SD. And multiple outliers can lead to masking. You might consider median absolute deviation, but that's not perfect either. Also,
Third, if you must determine outliers in a time series (and I don't think this is necessary very often), you have to look at the temporal aspect and not just z score. Looking at your graph, the high value around 2018 is much more of an outlier than the several points in the 2020s. I'd say the low value around 2008 is more of an outlier, too, despite not making the > 3 SD rule.
What I would do is add a smooth curve (via loess or spline or whatever) and look at deviations from that line. You could formalize this into some sort of rule (and maybe someone already has) but I'd just eyeball it. Judgment is a part of statistical analysis. It's not all reducible to algorithms.

Dear Peter Folm, Thank you for your answer. It's very explanatory. As you mentioned, I added two different smooth curves to the plot. (I posted these in question box) Please suggest possible points which may be outlier. And then I will search for whether any economic or other events occurred in these points) Thank you four your helps!

It looks like very noisy data, so maybe there are no outliers. But it's really a substantive question. An outlier is a surprising point. Which points surprise you? You can see for yourself which points are farthest from the line.
